# Hide rich:dataScroller Page Numbers

Tags: jsf, richfaces, datascroller

Is it possible to hide the page numbers shown by the rich:dataScroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use the pages facet for the datascroller which replaces the default page numbers controls

```
<rich:datascroller>
  <f:facet name="pages">
    <h:outputText value=""/>
  </facet>
</rich:datascroller>
```

Comment: it works for me. as long as you put something in the pages facet --- see my updated answer. What version of RF are you using? In RF4 there is a reported issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8701